# Implementing incremental builds

Tags: programming-languages, data-structures, compiler, builds

I'm working on a toy language.

Until now, multiple files have been compiled by merging the ASTs of each file and then running the semantic analysis and code generation phase on the merged AST.

Now I'd like to implement incremental builds. My language does not have header files. Therefore, I need to persist the symbol table between the compilation different files. One way would be to create a SQLite database that holds track of all symbols. When a file changes I could simply update the database.

My question is:

Is this a good idea? What is "state of the art" for compiling incrementally in a language with no header files?

Comment: It's a toy language; you can do whatever you want.  This would be the first time I've heard someone using a SQLite database to do it, but the approach seems viable.

Answer (score 3):

Some defer the symbol checking until runtime. This avoids the problem because each individual source file can be compiled without reference to any other file. Of course, you also lose compile time checking.

Some convert each source file into one or more compiled files. For example, the java compiler will produce one or more .class files for each .java file you ask it to compile. If the compiler needs to reference other files it can just read the .class files from disk.

Others use a single file to store all the needed data. Data pertaining to modules that didn't need to be recompiled can simply be read in from the old copy of the file. I understand that Microsoft's C# compiler did this before support for incremental mode was removed.

Answer (score -2):

Do as you like.  You will probably find that a strict schema will get in your way as you will be changing it constantly.  You are basically serializing the internal state of the compilation somehow and reading it in later.